# Does the Either type constructor contain a phantom type each for the left/right case?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, higher-kinded-types, type-constructor

AFAIK, only types are inhabited by values in Haskell, not type constructors. `Either` is a binary type constructor of kind `* -> * -> *`. `Left` and `Right` both apply this type constructor to a single type, which is provided by the passed value. Doesn't that mean that in both cases `Either` is merely partially applied and thus still a type constructor awaiting the missing type argument?

```
let x = Right 'x' -- Either a Char
```

`x` has the type `Either a Char`. I would assume that this type would have the kind `* -> *`. This is clearly a polymorphic type, not a ground one. Yet `Either a Char` can be inhabited by values like `'x'`.

My suspicion is that the type variable `a` is a phantom type for the `Right` case resp. `b` for `Left`. I know phantom types in connection with  `Const`, where the respective type variable isn't used at all. Am I on the right tack?

Comment: `Either Char` is a type constructor of kind `* -> *`. `Either Char a` is a type (of kind `*`) - it is shorthand for `forall a . Either Char a`; this must be a type because every `forall` is a type (has kind `*`). Neither type variable in `Either a b` can possibly be phantom, since if you have `x :: Either a b` then there may be an `a` contained within or there may be a `b`; you can only discover there is no `a` by pattern matching.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> AFAIK, only types are inhabited by values in Haskell, not type constructors.

Spot on.

> `Left` and `Right` both apply this type constructor to a single type

You can't say that. `Left` and `Right` don't live in the type language at all, so they don't apply anything to any types, they only apply themselves to *values*.

> `x` has the type `Either a Char`. I would assume that this type would have the kind `* -> *`

You need to distinguish between *function/constructor arguments*, and *type variables*. It's basically the distinction between [free and bound variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables). `Either a Char` still has kind `*`, not `* -> *`, because it is already applied to `a`. Yes, that's a type variable, but it still is an argument that's already applied.

> Yet `Either a Char` can be inhabited by values like `'x'`.

Not quite – it can be inhabited by values like `Right 'x'`.

> My suspicion is that the type variable `a` is a phantom type for the `Right` case resp. `b` for `Left`

kind of, but I wouldn't call it “phantom” because you can't just count out `Left` or `Right`. At least not unless you choose `Either Void b`, but in that case you don't have the `a` variable.

Comment: I still try to understand it. `Either a Char` is a monotype or type constant and `a` is just a placeholder for a particular type. With which type `a` is substituted depends on the context, e.g. `let t = Right 'x'` has type `Either Bool Char` in the context of `[Left True, t, Left False]`. Is this a proper reasoning?

Comment: Yes, that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that a type variable is phantom if and only if the choice of the type variable does not restrict what values can be passed to the type's constructors. The important part is that this is a type-centric definition. It is determined by looking only at the type definition, not at some particular value of the type.

So does it matter that no value of type `String` appears in the value `Left 5 :: Either Int String`? Not at all. What matters is that the choice of `String` in `Either Int String` prevents `Right ()` from type-checking.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell has "implicit universal quantification", which means that type variables have an implicit `forall`. `Either a Int` is equivalent to `forall a. Either a Int`.

One way to consider a `forall` is that it's like a lambda, but for type variables. If we use the syntax `@` for type application, then, you can "apply" a type to this and get a new type out.

```
let foo = Right 1 :: forall a. Either a Int
foo @Char   :: Either Char Int
foo @Double :: Either Double Int
```